# Issue with rails mailer and rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rake-task

If an agent hasn't been verified, I want one email to be generated and sent to me with all of their names. Not sure where I went wrong.

agent_card_mailer.rb

```
class AgentCardMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Help <help@email.com>"

  def not_verified_message(agent_card)
    @agent_card = agent_card

    mail(:to => "me@email.com", :subject => "Agent License Issues")
  end
end
```

not_verified_message.html.erb

```
Hi there,<br><br>

These agents have not been verified.<br><br>

<% @agent_cards.each do |agent_card| %>
  <%= agent_card.agent.name %><br>
<% end %>
```

issue_with_license.rake

```
namespace :agent_cards do
  desc 'Send out weekly email for agents with issues'
  task remind_license_issues: :environment do
    AgentCard.all.each do |agent_card|
      if agent_card.verified == false
        AgentCardMailer.not_verified_message(agent_card).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mailer is setting the attribute `@agent_card` but the template is looking for the plural `@agent_cards`

Comment: If you call Something by another name, the app can't find it. You set `@agent_card` in the controller then you have to use the same in the view. (It's only when dealing with models that you sometimes you pluralize like `@user=User.first` `@posts=@user.posts.all` post is pluralized here because you expect many)

Comment: Actually your `each do` will probably fail unless `agent_card` you pass in the `not_verified_message` method is a collection, not a single record. Give us all your models in order to help you. If, let's say, there is an Agent which is parent of Agent_card like `Agent has_many agent_cards` then pass the agent in the method and then you can retrieve all agent cards in the view...